# Delete row in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

I used

```
milsa <- edit(data.frame())
```

To open the R Data Editor and  now I can type the data of my table.
My problem is: my table has 36 rows, but for some reason I have 39 rows appearing in the program (the 3 additional rows are all filled with NA).
When I try to use:

```
length(civil)
```

I'm getting 39 instead of 36. How can I solve this? I am trying to use **fix(milsa)**  but it can't delete the additional rows.

PS: Civil is a variable of milsa.

Comment: Please save the RStudio tag for RStudio-specific problems, for example if you have R code that works on the R command line or R Gui, but doesn't work in RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

#### Subset with the index:

You can reassign the data.frame to itself with only the rows you want to keep.

`milsa <- milsa[1:36,]`

Here is a [LINK](https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) to a quick tutorial for your reference

Answer (score 0):

**To delete specific rows**

```
milsa <- milsa[-c(row_num1, row_num2, row_num3), ]
```

**To delete rows containing one or more NA's**

```
milsa <- na.omit(milsa)
```